# What does *PIPER mean in Perl?

Tags: perl, filehandle, typeglob

I need some help understanding the following Perl code snippet. I have the following two questions.

1.
What does local `*PIPER` mean? Even though I've done some Perl programming before the `local *` syntax is new to me. Is it a pointer?

2.
What is the purpose of

```
curl http://www.somesite.net/cgi-bin/updateuser.cgi? -d "userid=$userid&password=$password\" -s |"; ?
```

Thank You :)

```
local *PIPER;

$http_query = "curl http://www.somesite.net/cgi-bin/updateuser.cgi? -d \"userid=$userid&password=$password\" -s |";

open(PIPER,$http_query) or die "sorry";

while(<PIPER>)
{
   $rets = $_;

}

close(PIPER);

return $rets;
```

Comment: I would like to add that this piece of code is rather poorly written IMHO. Curl is available as a library, there's no reason to resort to using external commands.

Comment: Doesn't CPAN.pm use curl by default? Or at least in certain cases? I've never used curl myself, but I've seen it pop up when using the CPAN module.

Comment: No, CPAN.pm does not use curl by default. It tries pure Perl first, but if libwww-perl isn't installed it needs to fall back to something else.

Answer (score 10):

1) "`*PIPER`" is a typeglob. It is "`$PIPER`", "`@PIPER`", and "`%PIPER`" (and I then some) all in one. They are declaring all `*PIPER` names local to the code snippet you have.

2) That's a shell command. It ends with a `|` which means that that command is being run, and it's output is being piped in as the input for the filehandle `PIPER`. The program then reads this line-by-line with `while(<PIPER>)`, but you already know that.

I don't know much about `curl`, but I know it's a command-line program for doing stuff on the internet. Just a random stab, your code appears to be accessing a website's CGI script and sending it some information.

Comment: For a documentation a typeglobs look at http://www.perl.com/doc/manual/html/pod/perldata.html

Comment: Thanks Chris, your explanation really helped :)

Comment: In the days before 'use FileHandle;' or related modules, this was the standard way to provide yourself with a local 'file handle'.  These days, you don't normally need that notation - but STDERR, STDOUT, STDIN are relics of that bygone era.

Answer (score 6):

As others have noted, `*PIPER` is a typeglob so you can dynamically scope the PIPER filehandle. That's ancient Perl though. Use a lexical filehandle instead:

```
sub foo {
    my $http_query = "...";

    open my($piper), $http_query or die "sorry";

    while()
        {
        $rets = $_;
        }

    return $rets;
    }
```

You don't need to do any of this to send a POST request to a server though. You can do this completely within Perl using [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl).

Answer (score 3):

`local *PIPER;` is declaring the `PIPER` file handle to be local. Since file handles don't have their own type symbol, they need to be caught by typeglobs in order to be declared local.

`curl` is similar to `wget`; it is used to transfer a URL. See `man curl` for more details, but the `-d` switch (data) passes the following string as data in a POST operation, and the `-s` switch (silent) suppresses error output and a progress meter.

Answer (score 1):

2) This actual invocation of curl sends an HTTP POST request with the text 
\"userid=$userid&password=$password\" 
to 
http://www.somesite.net/cgi-bin/updateuser.cgi?
and outputs the response from the server (to the pipe). The -s flag strips the output from anything except what is coming from the server (such as error messages or progress meters).